# Non Repeating template in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-template

Most of the templates I have seen for angularjs work with `ng-repeat` or `ng-options`. I want a template to whom I can pass an object on click event of a button or something and the template is rendered only once . Like if I have template like following

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="questionnaire">
<div class="question">
<span> {{question.number}}</span>
<span>{{question.text}}</span>
</script>
```

I want to render this template as explained by following jquery code

```
$('a#link1').on('click',function(){
var question = {number:1, text:"My first Question"};
renderTemplate("questionnaire", question);

});
```

Indeed, I want to render the template when my anhcor tag with id `link1` is clicked. ngclick is for click event handling (which can be done either in jquery or angular using ngclick). My aim is to pass an object to the template myself rather than writing

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-include="questionnaire"></div>
```

The above approach will essentially look for questions attribute in $scope variable of the relevant controller. But I want the template rendered only for one object and I want the object be passed to template when it is about to be rendered not from the $scope variable.

How can I do that in Angualr?

Comment: Really unclear. `ngShow` with `ngClick`, maybe?

Comment: This would be a case where a directive would work best.

Comment: `I want the object be passed to template when it is about to be rendered not from the $scope variable`

I am not sure what you mean by this. Is binding the current question to a `$scope` variable somehow undesirable? If so, why?